# Backwards compatibility of the v3 mini controller: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

in Googles [CastVideos](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android) reference App the minSdkVersion is 10. When trying to run the App on an API 16 Emulator Instance (Android 4.1 x86) the App crashes immediately and i get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.sample.cast.refplayer/com.google.sample.cast.refplayer.VideoBrowserActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class fragment
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class fragment
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                  at com.google.sample.cast.refplayer.VideoBrowserActivity.onCreate(VideoBrowserActivity.java:111)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
               Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzni.zzbg(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzni.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.getSharedInstance(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.uicontroller.UIMediaController.<init>(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.MiniControllerFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1061)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1264)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1366)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2409)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:374)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                  at com.google.sample.cast.refplayer.VideoBrowserActivity.onCreate(VideoBrowserActivity.java:111) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
               Caused by: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzni.zzbg(Unknown Source) 
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzni.zza(Unknown Source) 
                  at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                  at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.getSharedInstance(Unknown Source) 
                  at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.uicontroller.UIMediaController.<init>(Unknown Source) 
                  at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.widget.MiniControllerFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source) 
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074) 
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1061) 
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1264) 
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1366) 
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2409) 
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120) 
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:374) 
                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33) 
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:75) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                  at com.google.sample.cast.refplayer.VideoBrowserActivity.onCreate(VideoBrowserActivity.java:111) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It acts as could the AppCompatActivity not inflate the MiniController Fragment, which is provided by the Cast v3 Framework.

Is this a problem of the Cast Framework or some kind of false configured emulator?

The same happens on my own App, where i added the Mini Controller Fragment to an AppCompatActivity as well.
On API 23 both Apps work perfectly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the Emulator image did not have the Google APIs (without the actual support library and play services the app crashes)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `google-play-services` version, if the version is not the same as you are developing the app will crash. To avoid this you can use the below code snippet which checks the currently installed version on the device and launches a dialog to update the `google-play-services`.

```
/**
 * Check play services version and go for update if not updated
 * @return
 */
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
            apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                    .show();
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "This device is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```